# Validate an XSD schema using XSD

Tags: xml, validation, xsd, schema

Since an XSD schema is a valid XML document itself, is there any main XSD document that could be used to validate any other XSD document?

In case you wonder why I need this, I am working with a program called B2B Data Transformation from Informatica and I am trying to programatically generate an xml document (which is in fact XSD) but the program requires an XSD document that can validate the generated xml.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. XML Schema is written in XML Schema itself and can be downloaded from [here](http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema)

Comment: @Devendra D. Chavan, I did click on the last word "here"